# docker cannot create directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

this is my docker compose yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=DB
      - MARIADB_USER=user
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=pass!
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
    volumes:
      - /Users/joachim/project/docker/mariadb/:/bitnami/mariadb
```

Im getting this error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied
```

How might i solve this?

Comment: Any particular reason you are sticking to version 2 of compose format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, I assume, that you're using MinGW as your bash environment (your path is UNIX-line path). To access your drive C you need to add `/c` at the beginning of your path.

So, your mount path will be equal to this path

```
/c/Users/joachim/project/docker/mariadb/
```